# How to "activate" certain parts of a code

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I want to "activate" parts of my code through buttons. I tried something like, when you press a button, the value of a variable is set to an other amount which activates another part of my code:

```
from tkinter import *
window = Tk()
window.title('Adventure')
c = Canvas(window, height=360, width=640, bg='black')
c.pack()

system = 1

def start():
    c.delete(anfang1)
    anfangbutton.destroy()

if system == 1:
    anfang1 = c.create_text(320, 180, text='Adventure', fill='white', font=('Halvatica', 50))
    anfangbutton = Button(window, text='Start', command=start)
    anfangbutton.place(x=320, y=250) # I want that if you press the button, start is activated and the value of "system" goes to 2, so the next part begins
if system == 2:
    anfang2 = c.create_text(320, 180, text='Adventure', fill='white', font=('Halvatica', 50))
```

I would appreciate if someone could help me with this or has another way of doing it

Comment: The function `start` can modify the variable `system` -- so what is the question? It isn't very clear what you are trying to do, but surely it isn't difficult to have `system` increment (or toggle or whatever it is that you want) when  `start()` is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code, I will explain:

```
def nextStage():
     #CODE#

def start():
    c.delete(anfang1)
    anfangbutton.destroy()
    anfang2 = c.create_text(320, 180, text='Adventure', fill='white', font=('Halvatica', 50))
    #then button or code to move onto next "stage"

def main():
    global anfang1
    global anfangbutton
    anfang1 = c.create_text(320, 180, text='Adventure', fill='white', font=('Halvatica', 50))
    anfangbutton = Button(window, text='Start', command=start)
    anfangbutton.place(x=320, y=250) # I want that if you press the button, start is activated and the value of "system" goes to 2, so the next part begins
main()
```

Basically, what I have done to try and combat the issue is two things.

Rather than trying to use a system variable and If/Else statements, I have put it all into functions. For tkinter, you want to build functions from the first one at the bottom of the page. So the last "stage" or function will be at the top (this is just so it can be properly referenced by the button).

I then globalised the variables so that start() would be able to destroy the buttons.

Not the most effective but works?